# I'm trying to find a specific link in a page with a python script

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I'm trying to figure out how to extract from a given site only the **links** with a specific text inside

This is the program i use:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

html_page = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.example.net/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
linkContent = "Tartan Flannel Shirt "
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    print link.get('href')
```

The **Html link** is like that

```
<a class="name-link" href="/shop/all/shirts">Tartan Flannel Shirt </a>
```

If i run the program above, the output is a list of every link in the site but i would like it to show only the link with **Tartan Flannel Shirt** inside.

Comment: It might be worth noting that you are missing the closing quote mark - so there is a syntax error in your script

Comment: using python 2 ?

Comment: @PatrickArtner do you suggest using Python3?

Comment: @AleksJ Thank's i didn't notice

Comment: I suggest tagging `python 2.x` if you use it - it is dead and python 3.9 is lurking so you are quite behind.

Answer (score 1):

You can supply lambda function to `text=` parameter of `.find_all()`. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = '''
    <a href="#1">Something else</a>
    <a href="#2">This link contains Tartan Flannel Shirt</a>
    <a href="#3">Something else</a>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.find_all('a', text=lambda t: 'Tartan Flannel Shirt' in t):
    print(link)
```

Prints:

```
<a href="#2">This link contains Tartan Flannel Shirt</a>
```

---

Similarly, you can search attributes this way, for example `href=` attributes of links:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = '''
    <a href="http://link1">Link1</a>
    <a href="http://link2">Link2</a>
    <a href="http://link3">Link3</a>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.find_all('a', href=lambda t: 'link2' in t):
    print(link)
```

Prints:

```
<a href="http://link2">Link2</a>
```

---

[Link to `beautifulsoup` API.](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kinds-of-filters)